# Bootstrap nav bar puts sign in button on a second line in safari

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, safari

In Safari the sign in button jumps down on it's own line. I haven't tried firefox, but it works fine on chrome. I have no other code other than this html. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Also I'm using safari 9.0.3

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Andrew Timosca</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- My CSS file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
  <!-- Google Fonts -->

  <!-- Makes this site work on mobile -->
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>
 <body>
  <!-- Nav Bar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign in</button>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <!-- Splash Content -->

  <!-- Latest Episode -->

  <!-- Footer -->

  <!-- Jquery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want the Sign in button to do?  Your question is not clear.

Comment: To be vertically centered with everything else. Check it out on safari and check it out on chrome

Answer (score 3):

Your `li` elements are floated left while your `button` has `display: inline-block`. When you mix floats and inline content the browser decides what to do based on its text layout metrics and different browsers may make different decisions.

If you want all of the elements on the same line, make them all floats or all inline-blocks and ensure that there's enough space for them on the same line. If you choose the inline-block approach you can also add `white-space: nowrap` to the containing `ul` element to prevent wrapping when the page is narrow.

Comment: So is this a bug within bootstrap? I have no custom css on this.

Comment: It's not really bootstrap's bug -- you should only have `li` elements inside a `ul`. Browsers won't enforce that but it looks like that's what bootstrap is assuming. Wrap the button in an `li` element. That will have the same affect as changing the CSS.

Comment: I believe it's a bug in bootstrap. The button breaks when wrapped in an `<li>` tag. All `.navbar-btn` should `float: left` inside `.navbar-right` imo.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue - including a button in the navbar list made it wrap to a second line in both Safari and Windows Edge. @Stephen-Nelson's answer clued me into what was wrong. The issue indeed was that the other li's in the list (which contain links), all had `float: left`.

This behavior was automatically added by Bootstrap. However, the button did not have that float property, because Bootstrap looks for the `<li>` to add the float behavior. So no need to change anything about the other items in the list. Wrapping the button in an `<li>` let Bootstrap apply the same behavior.

Here's what my code looks like now:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="/#content-1">Learn more</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pricing">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" ng-click="signin()">Sign in</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `<l1>` is not a valid tag, did you mean `<li>`?

Comment: was this typo just in your answer or was this the reason my suggested fix didn't work for you?

Comment: @StephenNelson - finally had a chance to go back and test it without the 'pull-left' and you're right that the typo was the problem. Now the wrapping <li> gets the correct behavior applied by bootstrap (basically the same thing as the pull-left class). Cleaning up the answer... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is made to wrap when your menu items exceed the width available.  Do a `Ctrl-` to resize your page a wee bit smaller and things should re-shuffle themselves to fit.  This is likely an issue with your screen display and with Safari setting things to a certain zoom level which is different to the zoom level in the other browsers.

Comment: Nope that didn't work. I don't think the default zoom level would be an issue.

Comment: Gotcha.  Look at the answer below, from @Stephen-Nelson .